# Creating a libsubstrate for iPhone Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, jailbreak

I am working on mobilesubstrate plugins on a JB iPhone. i have created a dylib in xcode for my iphone which builds fine for Device, but when i try to build it for Simulator, it gives me an error "_MSHOOKMESSAGE reference from: blah blah". I have placed all the headers in proper locations. I got libsubstrate from device but that is i think the problem. The libsubstrate from device is not gonna work for Simulator. So my question is how to create a libsubstrate for Simulator?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to use `MSHookMessageEx` (which superseded `MSHookMessage`), you can

```
#define MSHookMessageEx(class, selector, replacement, result) \
 (*(result) = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod((class), (selector)), (replacement)))
```

Of course, `MSHookMessageEx` in Mobile Substrate is more complex than this, but for testing purpose this is usually enough.

Comment: ohh thanks for the reply.
Can you please help me in using this too? I mean how to use it if i m hooking to SBApplicationIcon?

Currently i have this code

`Class _$SBAppIcon = objc_getClass("SBApplicationIcon");`
MSHookMessage(_$SBAppIcon,@selector(launch), (IMP) &__$check_AppIcon_Launch,nil); `

i got this code from some forum, and trying to learn that.

Comment: @raziiq: Yes. But the 4th argument should be a pointer to an `IMP` to receive the original launch method.

Comment: oh yes , nil should be replaced by something like "__Original_Method", right?

I am using the above mentioned code, but as i described in my question, i am getting that error of _MSHookMessage. So in order to use the method you just described, how can i change my code to the one you just described?

Comment: @raziiq: Yes, you should use `MSHookMessageEx`. (Don't insert this macro on the actual device though, as `libsubstrate` does provide the actual implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=103558
May be this can help you.
Good luck.